# Requesting data to Sharepoint 2013 using rest api service to integrate with angular app

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint-2013

I am learning sharepoint 2013 for a required incoming project. I has never worked on .net or any other ms technology so i would appreciate if the answers are dumb proof.

I have a server that is running sharepoint 2013 and iis v8.0
Currently i am having some issues, but the main one is that i am trying to access the api service from an angular application. I setted the mapping for intranet to the ip of the server and i can access the api through to the web browser.

I also setted the http response headers to "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : * in iis. However when i try to access the api using the angular $http object i am getting a message that says XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://x.x.x.x/_api/web. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http:// localhost : 9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

The idea is that the angular application is totally independant of sharepoint and any .net technology. All i want to do is use the rest api to get/edit data.
The request i am making looks like this:

```
angular.module('angYeoman2App')
  .factory('SharePointJSOMFactory', function SharePointJSOMFactory($http, $q) {

  var deffered = $q.defer();
  var data = [];  
  var myService = {};

  SharePointJSOMFactory.getTasksRESTAppWeb = function() {
    var restQueryUrl = "http://x.x.x.x/_api/web"; 
    $http({
      headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose' },
      method: 'GET',
      url: restQueryUrl
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
      console.log(data);
      deffered.resolve();
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
      console.log('error', data)
      deffered.resolve();
    });
    return deffered.promise;
  };
  SharePointJSOMFactory.data = function() { 
    return data; 
  };

  return SharePointJSOMFactory;
```

});

Any idea what i am doing wrong? I has read that i need to add <% Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") %> somewhere, but i don't have any idea to what file.

I also have another problem (not so relevant at this point): When i try to access to a subsite using the ip address it seems it is applying the theme of the parent and it doesn't load the content of the subsite. Any idea why?

Any help is welcome. Tks for your time, have a nice day.